# Change Color in SVG Path Without any id

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to change the color of this SVG that gets generated from a plugin.
It doesnt provide me with any id or anything.
The color change has to happen onload

```
<svg width="313" height="300" aria-label="A chart." style="overflow: hidden;"><defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_15"><filter id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_20"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset dx="1" dy="1"></feOffset><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.1"></feFuncA></feComponentTransfer><feMerge><feMergeNode></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter></defs><g><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="25.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">I de sidste 2 uger har jeg været glad</text><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="39.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">og i godt humør</text><rect x="60" y="16.5" width="193" height="25" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g><g><rect x="60" y="266" width="193" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g column-id="Hele tiden"><rect x="60" y="266" width="65" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="75" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Hele tiden</text></g><circle cx="65.5" cy="271.5" r="5.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3366cc"></circle></g>
<path d="M219,277L219,266L208,272Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></path>
<g><text text-anchor="middle" x="230.5" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc">1/3</text></g>
<path d="M242,266L253,272L242,277Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc"></path></g>
<g>
<path d="M65,141.8L65,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
<path d="M157,141.8L157,160.20000000000002L65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
<path d="M157,141.8L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,68.2L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#109618" stroke-width="1" fill="#109618"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.81557942304377" y="108.41117619608076" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g>
<g><path d="M157,215.40000000000003L157,233.80000000000004A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,157,215.40000000000003" stroke="#a52b0e" stroke-width="1" fill="#a52b0e"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,141.8L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#dc3912" stroke-width="1" fill="#dc3912"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.8155794230438" y="182.88882380391928" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g><g><path d="M249,141.8L249,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,233.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,249,141.8" stroke="#264d99" stroke-width="1" fill="#264d99"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,68.2A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,215.40000000000003L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#3366cc" stroke-width="1" fill="#3366cc"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="215.68676355791695" y="145.65" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">50%</text></g><g></g></svg>
```

If the color is #264d99 then i want to change it to #ff0000

I have tried using this code for the color change without any luck

```
function changeColor(){
    var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
    // console.log(svg.length);
    svg.addEventListener("load", function(){
        var svgpaths = Array.from(svg.contentDocument.querySelectorAll("path"));
        svgpaths.forEach(function (path) {
            if(path.hasAttribute("fill", "#264d99")){
                path.setAttribute("fill", "#ff0000");
            }
        });
    });
}

changeColor();
```

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelectorAll')" - your SVG here is not an external resource like an iframe'd document would be, you have it directly as part of your HTML - so the use of `contentDocument` makes no sense here. You want `svg.querySelectorAll("path")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### try the following pure `js` solutions

1. single `svg` tag

```js
function changeColor(){
  const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
  // console.log(`svg =`, svg);
  svg.addEventListener("load", function(){
    const paths = [...svg.querySelectorAll("path")];
    paths.forEach((path) => {
      // check fill color ✅
      if(path.getAttribute("fill") === "#264d99"){
        path.setAttribute("fill", "#ff0000");
      }
    });
  });
}
changeColor();
```

2. multi `svg` tags

```js
function changeColor(){
  // get multi svg ✅
  const svgs = document.querySelectorAll("svg");
  for (const svg of svgs) {
    svg.addEventListener("load", function(){
      const paths = [...svg.querySelectorAll("path")];
      paths.forEach(function (path) {
        // check fill color ✅
        if(path.getAttribute("fill") === "#264d99"){
          path.setAttribute("fill", "#ff0000");
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
changeColor();
```

> demos

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if i want to do it to multiple SVG at once? i have 5 svgs i want to change the colors on. They're all missing id. I have tried your solution with a foreach with the svgs without any help. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: That's another question, show me your code.

Comment: This is the code :
function changeColor(){
    var svg = document.querySelectorAll("svg");
    console.log(svg.length);

    svg.forEach(function (svg) {

        svg.addEventListener("load", function(){
        var svgpaths = Array.from(svg.querySelectorAll("path"));
        svgpaths.forEach(function (path) {

            if(path.getAttribute("fill") === "#264d99"){
            path.setAttribute("fill", "#ff0000");
            }
        });
        });
    });


  }
  changeColor();

Comment: It doesnt work on 2 svgs only on 1.

Comment: see my update for multi svgs

Comment: For me the code doesnt work. It only works when I have one svg, but if I have 2 svgs it doesnt color any of them.

Comment: what's wrong with the code? Show me your 2 svg codes that not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255100/discussion-between-xgqfrms-and-tomah4wk).

Answer (score 3):

What about to override by css?

```css
path[fill="#264d99"] {
    fill: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<svg width="313" height="300" aria-label="A chart." style="overflow: hidden;"><defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_15"><filter id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_20"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset dx="1" dy="1"></feOffset><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.1"></feFuncA></feComponentTransfer><feMerge><feMergeNode></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter></defs><g><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="25.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">I de sidste 2 uger har jeg været glad</text><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="39.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">og i godt humør</text><rect x="60" y="16.5" width="193" height="25" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g><g><rect x="60" y="266" width="193" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g column-id="Hele tiden"><rect x="60" y="266" width="65" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="75" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Hele tiden</text></g><circle cx="65.5" cy="271.5" r="5.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3366cc"></circle></g>
<path d="M219,277L219,266L208,272Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></path>
<g><text text-anchor="middle" x="230.5" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc">1/3</text></g>
<path d="M242,266L253,272L242,277Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc"></path></g>
<g>
<path d="M65,141.8L65,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
<path d="M157,141.8L157,160.20000000000002L65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
<path d="M157,141.8L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,68.2L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#109618" stroke-width="1" fill="#109618"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.81557942304377" y="108.41117619608076" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g>
<g><path d="M157,215.40000000000003L157,233.80000000000004A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,157,215.40000000000003" stroke="#a52b0e" stroke-width="1" fill="#a52b0e"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,141.8L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#dc3912" stroke-width="1" fill="#dc3912"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.8155794230438" y="182.88882380391928" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g><g><path d="M249,141.8L249,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,233.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,249,141.8" stroke="#264d99" stroke-width="1" fill="#264d99"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,68.2A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,215.40000000000003L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#3366cc" stroke-width="1" fill="#3366cc"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="215.68676355791695" y="145.65" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">50%</text></g><g></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert all the `#264d99` colours inside the SVG to `#ff0000`. The easiest way would probably be a simple `replace()` call when reading the SVG as string.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
svg.outerHTML = svg.outerHTML.replace(/#264d99/gi, "#ff0000");
```

```js
function changeColor(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
  svg.outerHTML = svg.outerHTML.replace(/#264d99/gi, "#ff0000");
}

document.forms["update-color"].addEventListener("submit", changeColor);
```

```html
<form id="update-color"><button>update colour</button></form>

<svg width="313" height="300" aria-label="A chart." style="overflow: hidden;"><defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_15"><filter id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_20"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset dx="1" dy="1"></feOffset><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.1"></feFuncA></feComponentTransfer><feMerge><feMergeNode></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter></defs><g><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="25.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">I de sidste 2 uger har jeg været glad</text><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="39.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">og i godt humør</text><rect x="60" y="16.5" width="193" height="25" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g><g><rect x="60" y="266" width="193" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g column-id="Hele tiden"><rect x="60" y="266" width="65" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="75" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Hele tiden</text></g><circle cx="65.5" cy="271.5" r="5.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3366cc"></circle></g>
<path d="M219,277L219,266L208,272Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></path>
<g><text text-anchor="middle" x="230.5" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc">1/3</text></g>
<path d="M242,266L253,272L242,277Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc"></path></g>
<g>
<path d="M65,141.8L65,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
<path d="M157,141.8L157,160.20000000000002L65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
<path d="M157,141.8L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,68.2L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#109618" stroke-width="1" fill="#109618"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.81557942304377" y="108.41117619608076" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g>
<g><path d="M157,215.40000000000003L157,233.80000000000004A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,157,215.40000000000003" stroke="#a52b0e" stroke-width="1" fill="#a52b0e"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,141.8L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#dc3912" stroke-width="1" fill="#dc3912"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.8155794230438" y="182.88882380391928" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g><g><path d="M249,141.8L249,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,233.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,249,141.8" stroke="#264d99" stroke-width="1" fill="#264d99"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,68.2A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,215.40000000000003L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#3366cc" stroke-width="1" fill="#3366cc"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="215.68676355791695" y="145.65" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">50%</text></g><g></g></svg>
```

In your given scenario it would replace both the `fill` and `stroke` colours.

The main downside is that **all registered event handlers are removed**, since SVG DOM structure has to be rebuild. There is also no option to replace some of the colours, but not all (unless you build a more complicated regex).

Answer (score 0):

You can query all `<path>` elements with a specific fill color using an attribute selector.

```js
function changeColor() {
      const paths = document.querySelectorAll("path[fill='#264d99']");
      paths.forEach( path=> {
          path.setAttribute("fill", "#ff0000");
      });
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e)=>{
  changeColor();
})
```

```html
<svg width="313" height="300" aria-label="A chart." style="overflow: hidden;"><defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_15"><filter id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_20"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset dx="1" dy="1"></feOffset><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.1"></feFuncA></feComponentTransfer><feMerge><feMergeNode></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter></defs><g><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="25.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">I de sidste 2 uger har jeg været glad</text><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="39.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">og i godt humør</text><rect x="60" y="16.5" width="193" height="25" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g><g><rect x="60" y="266" width="193" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g column-id="Hele tiden"><rect x="60" y="266" width="65" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="75" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Hele tiden</text></g><circle cx="65.5" cy="271.5" r="5.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3366cc"></circle></g>
    <path d="M219,277L219,266L208,272Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></path>
    <g><text text-anchor="middle" x="230.5" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc">1/3</text></g>
    <path d="M242,266L253,272L242,277Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc"></path></g>
    <g>
    <path d="M65,141.8L65,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
    <path d="M157,141.8L157,160.20000000000002L65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
    <path d="M157,141.8L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,68.2L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#109618" stroke-width="1" fill="#109618"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.81557942304377" y="108.41117619608076" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g>
    <g><path d="M157,215.40000000000003L157,233.80000000000004A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,157,215.40000000000003" stroke="#a52b0e" stroke-width="1" fill="#a52b0e"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,141.8L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#dc3912" stroke-width="1" fill="#dc3912"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.8155794230438" y="182.88882380391928" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g><g><path d="M249,141.8L249,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,233.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,249,141.8" stroke="#264d99" stroke-width="1" fill="#264d99"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,68.2A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,215.40000000000003L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#3366cc" stroke-width="1" fill="#3366cc"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="215.68676355791695" y="145.65" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">50%</text></g><g></g></svg>
<svg width="313" height="300" aria-label="A chart." style="overflow: hidden;"><defs id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_15"><filter id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_20"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur><feOffset dx="1" dy="1"></feOffset><feComponentTransfer><feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.1"></feFuncA></feComponentTransfer><feMerge><feMergeNode></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode></feMerge></filter></defs><g><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="25.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">I de sidste 2 uger har jeg været glad</text><text text-anchor="start" x="60" y="39.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">og i godt humør</text><rect x="60" y="16.5" width="193" height="25" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect></g><g><rect x="60" y="266" width="193" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g column-id="Hele tiden"><rect x="60" y="266" width="65" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect><g><text text-anchor="start" x="75" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Hele tiden</text></g><circle cx="65.5" cy="271.5" r="5.5" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3366cc"></circle></g>
    <path d="M219,277L219,266L208,272Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></path>
    <g><text text-anchor="middle" x="230.5" y="275.35" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc">1/3</text></g>
    <path d="M242,266L253,272L242,277Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#0011cc"></path></g>
    <g>
    <path d="M65,141.8L65,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
    <path d="M157,141.8L157,160.20000000000002L65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8" stroke="#0c7112" stroke-width="1" fill="#0c7112"></path>
    <path d="M157,141.8L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,68.2L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#109618" stroke-width="1" fill="#109618"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.81557942304377" y="108.41117619608076" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g>
    <g><path d="M157,215.40000000000003L157,233.80000000000004A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,160.20000000000002L65,141.8A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,157,215.40000000000003" stroke="#a52b0e" stroke-width="1" fill="#a52b0e"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,65,141.8L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#dc3912" stroke-width="1" fill="#dc3912"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="97.8155794230438" y="182.88882380391928" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">25%</text></g><g><path d="M249,141.8L249,160.20000000000002A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,233.8L157,215.40000000000003A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,0,249,141.8" stroke="#264d99" stroke-width="1" fill="#264d99"></path><path d="M157,141.8L157,68.2A92,73.60000000000001,0,0,1,157,215.40000000000003L157,141.8A0,0,0,0,0,157,141.8" stroke="#3366cc" stroke-width="1" fill="#3366cc"></path><text text-anchor="start" x="215.68676355791695" y="145.65" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">50%</text></g><g></g></svg>
```

There is no need to first query all parent `<svg>` elements - unless you need to exclude some svgs also containing these fill colors.

Comment: When I run this on my macbook in VScode and in chrome browser it doesnt seem to work. When I run the code here on the website it works. It's so weird. Also when I try to run the code on wordpress with codesnippets it doesnt seem to work. Do you have any fix or know why?

Comment: Please check your Dev tools console. Probably the rest of your page has errors (other script, HTML nesting issues etc) VSCode's live preview is also quite error prone. If your charts are generated dynamically (via JS) they might not yet exist when selecting the svgs. So make sure to run the color script after the charts were appended to DOM.